# Breadth First Search in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, navigation, breadth-first-search

```
function BFS_search(data, start, ende){
    var queue = new Array();
    var steps = 0;
    for(var x=0; x<data.Adjazenzen.length-1; x++){  //push start Element in Queue
        if(data.Adjazenzen[x] == start){
            queue.push(data.Adjazenzen[x]);
            steps++;
            break;
        }
    }

    while(queue.length != 0) {
        var t = queue.pop();
        if(t.Von == ende) {
            return t.Von;
        }
        if(t.Nach == ende){
            return t.Nach;
        }
        else{
            queue.push(data.Adjazenzen[0]);
            data.Adjazenzen.shift();
            steps++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return "keine Ergebnis";
}
```

This code snippet should calculate the best route between two points from a given JSON Object and also add all Points between the start and end node. Basically it should be a navigation-system using BFS.

The JSON Object looks like this:

```
{"Adjazenzen":[
{"Von":"A1.02","Nach":"G-A3-1","X":"5778","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"A1.04","Nach":"G-A3-1","X":"5025","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"A1.05","Nach":"G-A3-1","X":"4212","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"A1.06","Nach":"G-A3-1","X":"3016","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"A1.07","Nach":"G-A3-1","X":"2354","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"A1.08","Nach":"G-A3-1","X":"1856","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":"1","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"A1.12","Nach":"G-A3-1","X":"1313","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"B1.01","Nach":"G-B3-1","X":"6572","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":"1","Gebaeude":"B","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-1","Nach":"G-A3-2","X":"906","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":{},"Gebaeude":{},"Level":{}},
    {"Von":"G-A3-1","Nach":"B1.01","X":"6572","Y":"223","Z":"3","Treppe":"1","Gebaeude":"B","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-2","Nach":"A1.14","X":"1066","Y":"1333","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-2","Nach":"G-A3-3","X":"1444","Y":"4016","Z":"3","Treppe":{},"Gebaeude":{},"Level":{}},
    {"Von":"G-A3-2","Nach":"A1.15","X":"1207","Y":"2340","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-2","Nach":"A1.18","X":"1444","Y":"4016","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-2","Nach":"A1.16","X":"1327","Y":"3188","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-2","Nach":"A1.13","X":"933","Y":"383","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-2","Nach":"A1.17","X":"1425","Y":"3884","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-3","Nach":"A1.19","X":"2691","Y":"3977","Z":"3","Treppe":"1","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-3","Nach":"A1.22","X":"2946","Y":"3969","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-3","Nach":"A1.23","X":"2946","Y":"3969","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"},
    {"Von":"G-A3-3","Nach":"A1.20","X":"1990","Y":"4002","Z":"3","Treppe":"0","Gebaeude":"A","Level":"0"}]}
```

You can ignore everything except Von (From) and Nach (To).
The problem is that my BFS is not 100% working and I don't know how to fix it.

An Example:
If you want to calculate from A1.04 to A1.15 it should add:
A1.04, G-A3-1, G-A3-2, A1.15

And if you want from A1.04 to A1.20:
A1.04, G-A3-1, G-A3-2, G-A3-3, A1.20

I hope you can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is `Adjazenzen` suppose to be an adjacency list?

Comment: Yes it is. The nodes are the navigation points.

Comment: @user2325235 Shouldn't `data.Adjazenzen[x] == start` be `data.Adjazenzen[x].Von === start`?

Comment: @Vivin Paliath I changed it into this `data.Adjazenzen[x].Von == start || data.Adjazenzen[x].Nach == start` because start is a String which is entered in a input field and read onclick

Comment: @user2325235 Another thing I see is your data. It seems to look like a list of edges, rather than an adjacency list.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath Ok, that's true. So a depth-first search would be a better solution?

Comment: @user2325235 You'll probably have to do some parsing to actually get a graph representation of your data. No graph traversal algorithm will work properly on a shuffled list of edges.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I notice is that `queue.push(...)` and `queue.pop()` will not work has you expect, because what you have then is a stack, which means that you're doing a *depth*-first search and not a *breadth*-first search.

Recall that a queue is a FIFO container. So, use `queue.push(...)` (which adds an element to the end of the array) and `queue.shift()` (which removes an element from the front of the array). Basically, `shift()` is similar to the `dequeue()` operation on a queue.